# Marquee - line breaking into two instead of a single line - css

Tags: html, css, marquee

My div css looks like

```
#another_div
{
    white-space:pre-wrap;
    font-size:1.5em;
    position:fixed;
    height:6%;
    display:block;
    background:#FFF;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    top:30%;
    padding-top:1%;
    -webkit-marquee: auto medium infinite scroll normal;   
    overflow-x: -webkit-marquee;


}
```

In this div I am loading some dynamic content coming from some page. It's showing like

> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>
> ```
>                          BBBBBBBBBB
> ```

But I want it as

> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBB

I already tried the `"white-space": "nowrap"`. Didn't work.

It's a marquee so it should be floating in a single line. Why is it breaking?? I checked the line. There is no line breaking tag. **How can I make it marquee in a single line?**

Comment: Are you sure there is no issue with the content that are coming from the dynamic pages?

Comment: yeah sure. I have checked that several times. @Kangkan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`white-space: nowrap;` should work. Check the demo below

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/inuviQo/9/)**

Comment: Thanks it worked. I was using <div id="another_div"></div>. And now set it to <marquee id="another_div"></marquee> and white-space: nowrap; worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

`white-space: pre;` will take out all your breaks!